# Routing a web applications endpoints to separate EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, routing, load-balancing

I currently have a domain of `www.example.com` which ultimately is routed to a Jetty web server. Many endpoints exist within this domain such as `/register`, `/sign-in` and `/about`. All of these endpoints are served by the same codebase.

The architecture I currently have is something similar to:

`AWS Route 53 -> ELB -> (ASG) Application [jetty]`

What I wish to do is split my codebase out into 3 which would ultimately mean I have 3 EC2 instances running `/register`, `/sign-in` and `/about`.

Naturally I would like to retain scalability - but I'd like to avoid using the AWS ALB.

This is the above solution I'm currently looking at, my questions are around - does this seem reasonable? Are there any latency issues with having hopping through 2 ELBs? Are there any other unforeseen issues with this type of architecture and what are the alternatives.

```
AWS Route 53 -> ELB -> (ASG) Nginx Routing -> ELB -> (ASG) Application [jetty]
                                           -> ELB -> (ASG) Application [jetty]
                                           -> ELB -> (ASG) Application [jetty]
```

Ultimately I wish to route different endpoints to different EC2 instances whilst retaining scalability.

Comment: That's an odd manual way to scale. I'd deploy everything to one machine and use auto scaling. In your proposed design I can't see why you'd need three ELB, you'd just route from Nginx to each application server. I suggest you edit your question to include more background on why you want to go with a fairly non-standard scaling scheme.

Comment: Why are you attempting to solve *exactly* the problem that ALB solves with *one* balancer... distributing requests to multiple targets (which can be multiple groups of instances) based on the request path... with 4 Classic ELBs and Nginx?  This is definitely doing things the hard way... so what is your motivation?